# CakePHP 3.0 throwing 'field required' error on non-empty field

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm having difficulty with my CakePHP 3.0 site throwing an error when it shouldn't.  I'm building an "Add Page" form, shown below:

```
echo $this->Form->create($newpage);
echo $this->Form->control('title');
echo $this->Form->control('content');
echo $this->Form->button('Save');
echo $this->Form->end();
```

The title and content are required.  Once the form is submitted, 'title' is used to generate a page 'name', which is currently just the title in lowercase and with spaces removed (so "About Us" would have the name "aboutus"). This name is also saved, but must be unique (eg if you had pages with titles "No Space" and "NOSpace" they would both end up with the name "nospace" even though the titles are unique).

I have the following validation rules in PagesTable.php:

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator = new Validator();

    $validator
        ->requirePresence('title','content')
        ->lengthBetween('title', [0, 50])
        ->add(
            'name',
            ['unique' => [
                'rule' => 'validateUnique',
                'provider' => 'table',
                'message' => 'Not unique']
            ]
            );

    return $validator;

}
```

The form is submitted to the controller, which contains this:

```
public function add($mainpage_id = null) {
    $newpage = $this->Pages->newEntity();

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $newpage = $this->Pages->patchEntity($newpage, $this->request->data);
        // Get page name by removing spaces from title
        $name = strtolower(str_replace(' \'\"', '', $newpage->title));
        // Get navigation order by getting number of current siblings, and adding 1
        $siblings = $this->Pages->find('all')
                                ->where(['parent_id' => $newpage->parent_id])
                                ->count();
        $nav_order = $siblings + 1;
        $newpage = $this->Pages->patchEntity($newpage, ['name' => $name, 'nav_order' => $nav_order]);
        if ($newpage->errors()) {
            $errors = $newpage->errors();
            if(isset($errors['name'])) {
                $this->Flash->error('The title you have entered is too similar to one that already exists. To avoid confusion, please choose a different title.');
            }else {
                $this->Flash->error('Please correct errors below');
            }
        }else {
            $this->Pages->save($newpage);
            $page_id = $newpage->id;
            $this->Flash->success('Page created');
            return $this->redirect('/admin/pages/index');
            exit;
        }
    }

    $this->set(compact('newpage'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['newpage']);
}
```

However, when I try to submit a page, I get "This field is required" on the title field even if I've entered a title.  In fact, it won't let me submit the form without entering a title (a message pops up saying "Fill out this field"), but then it throws the error.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: After doing patchEntity, check whether the title field has any value is set for it or not ...

Comment: Might be an issue with `$_accessible`?

Comment: Start with fixing the [**`requirePresence()` call**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#requiring-field-presence), it doesn't take multiple fields as separate arguments.

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed that call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codebase looks good. However, this might be not obvious behavior: [calling patch entity method validate the passed patch data](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/ORM/Marshaller.php#L561).
So the first time your patch is validated here:

`$newpage = $this->Pages->patchEntity($newpage, $this->request->data);`

and second time it's validated here:

`$newpage = $this->Pages->patchEntity($newpage, ['name' => $name, 'nav_order' => $nav_order]);`

and as second patch have no title, then validator said that it missed. To fix this you need to run patch once with all the data, i.e.:

```
    $data = $this->request->data();
    // Get page name by removing spaces from title
    $data['name'] = strtolower(str_replace(' \'\"', '', $data['title']));
    // Get navigation order by getting number of current siblings, and adding 1
    $siblings = $this->Pages->find('all')
                            ->where(['parent_id' => $data['parent_id']])
                            ->count();
    $data['nav_order'] = $siblings + 1;
    $newpage = $this->Pages->patchEntity($newpage, $data);
```

Hope you understand the idea, and it'll help.

UPDATE: just noticed that there might be no parent_id in request... You can move this logic into [afterSave](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#aftersave) callback in PagesTabe:

```
public function afterSave(Event $event, EntityInterface $entity) {
    $siblings = $this->count()
        ->where(['parend_id '=> $entity->parent_id]);
    // updateAll won't trigger the same hook again
    $this->updateAll(
            ['nav_order' => ++$siblings],
            ['id' => $entity->id]
    );
}
```

Comment: (I already had parent_id in a select field in the form, just removed it to make things easier while I was trying to sort this out. But that afterSave callback is really useful to know; I hadn't spotted that in the documentation.)

Comment: if you get parent_id from request - probably better to leave it in controller. Don't forget to add validation for it too - probably `isNumber`

Comment: That’s what I figured. Thanks!

Comment: I had a similar issue with 2 patchEntities - the first I used `$this->getRequest()->getData()` and the second I was patching in some custom data. I got around the issue by doing an array merge of getData() and my custom data array. Thus only requiring a single patch (and therefore validation).